# Grep on Apache access log fails to match forward slash

Tags: grep

I am trying to match and get a count of the occurrences of the string 'item/' for a particular date from a particular IP address in this Apache2 access log - here is a typical line:

`66.249.79.148 - - [21/Dec/2017:13:26:17 +0000] "GET /item/foobar/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8807 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

Why, you may ask? I want to know how many times a day the Googlebot is hitting sub-pages under 'item/' on my site. I am doing it this way because I just need a quick-and-dirty solution, and those files can get pretty big too.

If I use: `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep -wc 'item'` I get a proper count. Problem is there may be other occurrences of the word 'item' in my URLs. Really I want to match 'item/'. However, nothing I try seems to work - all these return a zero count:

- `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep
  -wc "item/"`
- `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep
  -wc item/`
- `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep -wc item\/`
- `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep
  -wc "item\/"`
- `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep -wc "item/"`

I didn't think forward slashes needed to be escaped, anyway? To add to the mystery, `grep 21\/Dec` works fine.

I am missing something really obvious here...

Comment: probably the `-w` is causing issue because after `item/` you have word characters...

Comment: Well, you are right! Now I think about it, I don't even know why I had the -w, it's not necessary. `grep 66.249 /opt/lamp*/apache2/logs/access_log | grep 21\/Dec | grep -c item/` works just fine! Thanks!